# Pandas Data-Frame : Conditionally select columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data-frame as shown below...

```
   C1  C2   C3     C4
0  -1   -3   3   0.75
1  10   20  30  -0.50
```

I want to add only the first two columns in each row which have a value less than zero. For example, the series I would get for the above case would be as below...

```
   CR
0  -4
1  0
```

I know how to apply other functions like the below...

```
df.iloc[:, :-2].abs().sum(axis = 1)
```

Is there a way using lambda functions?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and `sum`:

```
df = df.iloc[:,:2].where(df < 0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
0   -4.0
1    0.0
dtype: float64
```

If need solution with [selection by callable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

```
df = df.iloc[:, lambda df: [0,1]].where(df < 0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
0   -4.0
1    0.0
dtype: float64
```

For `lambda` function in `python` is applicable here too.

**lambda in pandas**:

```
#sample data
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2
4  4  1  5  3  4
```

Get difference by rows `.apply(axis=0)` what is default so same `.apply()`:

```
#instead function f1 is possible use lambda, if function is simple
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min()))
A    8
B    8
C    8
D    7
E    6
dtype: int64

def f1(x):
    #print (x)
    return x.max() - x.min()

print (df.apply(f1))
A    8
B    8
C    8
D    7
E    6
dtype: int64
```

Get difference by columns `.apply(axis=1)`

```
#instead function f2 is possible use lambda, if function is simple
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min(), axis=1))
0    5
1    5
2    8
3    9
4    4
dtype: int64

def f2(x):
    #print (x)
    return x.max() - x.min()

print (df.apply(f2, axis=1))
0    5
1    5
2    8
3    9
4    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The .where clause is what I needed. I did not understand the lambda syntax - can you point me to some good resources for that? Thank you.

Comment: lambda in pandas - I cannot find some nice resource. :(

Comment: I try add some sample with lambda functions, I hope it help.

Comment: hi, i did nt want to raise another question since stackoverflow will mark it as duplicate.          but why doesnt something like this work                                       
                df.iloc[:,lambda x:x.sex=='M']                                                                    
 for a dataframe consisting of two columns, id(range(1,7) and sex(M/F).                                                   it gives me NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

Comment: @user1906450 - I think need `print(df[df.sex=='M'])` - [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: @jezrael hey ..u r right..that selection works definitely..but i was trying to get iloc to work with a callable. works fine when i use callable on loc. i dont understand why it doesnt work with iloc. let me know if u need me to open a new question....i could give code samples

Comment: hmm, for iloc need `(df.sex=='M').values` - convert boolean Series to 1d numpy array

Comment: it doesnt give me error..but doesnt select only M ..returns every single row :(

Comment: `df.iloc[lambda x:(x.sex=='M').values]` should help :)

Comment: yeaaaahhhh worked... woaah this is crazy though... this doesnt work a.iloc[:,lambda x : (x.sex=='M').values] but this does a.iloc[lambda x : (x.sex=='M').values]... when i add row slice it returns me every single row..when i dont it only returns me male rows